# cant access camera roll in photos react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want to access the phone camera roll photos, in React-native by this code:

```
_handleButtonPress = () => {

    CameraRoll.getPhotos({
        first: 20,
        assetType: 'Photos',
    })
        .then(r => {
            this.setState({ photos: r.edges });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            alert(err)
        });
};
```

but i get this Error in alert:

> could not get photos need: read_external_storage permission

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the Google [**Docs**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview), *if the device is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, and the app's targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher, the user isn't notified of any app permissions at install time.*

Therefore you *must ask the user to grant the dangerous permissions at runtime*

[**Here's**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups) a list of Dangerous Permissions.

You can enable the permissions in React Native as

```
try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      {
        'title': 'Access Storage',
        'message': 'Access Storage for the pictures'
      }
    )
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log("You can use read from the storage")
    } else {
      console.log("Storage permission denied")
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err)
  }
```

Check [**here**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid) for more details

Comment: Error : getting `await is the reserved word`

Comment: `await` must be used inside  `async` method

Answer (score 0):

i added this code in AndroidManifest located at(( Example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

then i confirmed app permissions in android(and i dont know how to do it at run time) and problem solved.